Returning a generator as return value, and the generator becomes empty
I am puzzled by the following snippet:
def iter_test(x):
    l = [1,2,3,4,5]
    default = (i for i in l)
    if x:
        return default
    else:
        for i in default:
            yield i

def test_iter():
    a = iter_test(True)
    b = iter_test(False)
    print(a, b)
    print('a', list(a))
    print('b', list(b))

test_iter()

The output is:
<generator object iter_test at 0x00000171F1A82B50> <generator object iter_test at 0x00000171F1A82DC0>
a []
b [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

This snippet tests two different methods of returning an iterator
in a function.

In the first method, the iterator itself, default
is returned.
In the second method, the iterator was firstly unpacked with for,
then its contents are yield'd one by one.

With print(a, b) we could see that both method
returns a generator object. However, the generator
returned by the first method is instead empty.
Since the type of a is generator, the iterator should be
returned successfully. How does it turn into an empty
generator instead?
My Python version is Python 3.12.2.

Generator functions are defined whenever a yield statement is included in the body.
def foo():
    return 1

def bar():
    return 1
    yield None

print(foo()) # 1
print(bar()) # <empty generator>

One possible way to work around this is to yield arrays one-by-one if originally intending a return.
